# Map non-existent commands in Ubuntu to existing commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux as my main terminal in VSCode. I always use the command "cmd.exe" to switch to command prompt when I need it, but I often forget to add the ".exe" and just type in "cmd". Is there a way to map "cmd" to "cmd.exe" so that it executes even if I don't type in the full thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would avoid any such magic since it sounds like it'll cause confusion down the road when my commands don't work for other people or in different contexts:

```
alias cmd="cmd.exe"
```

But you can easily do what you want by creating a `command_not_found_handle` to automatically look for a `.exe` file:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  if type "$1.exe" > /dev/null 2>&1
  then
    "$1.exe" "${@:2}"
  else
    echo "$1 and $1.exe not found" >&2
    return 127
  fi
}
```